# How Do I make student code not overwrite the previous code by changing the cell it is put into

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
users = []
firstname = input("what is your first name:")
lastname = input ("what is your last name:")
year = input ("what year did you join the school:")
inital = firstname[0:1]

code = ( year+lastname+inital)
for i in users:
 if code == i:
  print("This username already exists",code)
  code = code+"#"
print("-"*30)
print ("your student code is:",code)
print("-"*30)
users.append(code)

sheet.update("A3",code)
```

**I want to make the cell that the student code is put into change each time it is run

currently i can only make it keep overwriting in A3**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as stated in the documentation [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.append_row) you can use the method that appends a new row to the spread sheet so the students are listed one after another, one per line.

the code to update is:

```py
sheet.update("A3",code)
```

### replace it with:

```py
sheet.append_row([code])
```

### Note:

the string `code` must be put into a list as `append_row` takes a list of values.